# Error loading page localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to create a new database using the phpmyadmin. But my laptop is unable to search everytime I type `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

I already changed the

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

and

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

as recommend but still I got an error saying **"HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."**

I'm also using the latest version of xampp which is 1.8 but my xampp can't install the apache, only can install the mysql.

Comment: Have you tried opening the XAMPP Control Panel, and Start the necessary module that you wanted?

Comment: @LoganWayne yes, now that my apache is working, i clicked start on apache and mysql but still can't access to localhost/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your port number. You can do it with these following instructions:

1.)Open your XAMPP

2.)From XAMPP, you will see actions buttons (Start, Admin, Config, Logs). From the Apache, click the config button and go to Apache (httpd.confg)

3.)It will open the httpd.confg file in notepad by default. Press ctrl + f and look for "Listen". It's within line's 50 - 60.

4.) Try to comment the current listen by adding a # sign and type a new port number like 1337 like this:

`#Listen 12.34.56.78:80`

`Listen 1337`

Comment: I changed my port number and my apache is working now. But the problem is I still can't open localhost/phpmyadmin.

Comment: Have you tried localhost:1337? Since you changed the port number, it should also change the url. It should be something like this localhost:1337/phpmyadmin